# Https request reaching twice to server android

Tags: java, android, http

My post request code as follows

When post request  to the server it reach twice in  to the server
and i am sure call httpRequest once.When i call once the request reach server twice or thrise;

```
private void invokePostOrderRestService(
            final RestPostDataCallback<Order> callback,
            final RequestOrder requestOrder) {
        String URL = BASE_URL + "postOrder";
        Log.e("post ordercccccc", "orderPosted");

        JSONObject jsonObject = convertOrderRequestToJson(requestOrder);

        if (jsonObject != null) {

            OrderProApplication
                    .getContext()
                    .getRestClient()
                    .postJsonObject(URL, jsonObject,
                            new ResponseListener<JSONObject>() {

                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(JSONObject response) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                    Log.e("Order Post Success","Post Order  Successssssssssssssssss");
                                    String status = "";
                                    try {
                                        status = response.getString("status");
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    if (status.equals("OK")) {
                                        callback.onRestPostDataCompleted(
                                                ResultCode.RESULT_OK, null);
                                    } else {
                                        callback.onRestPostDataCompleted(
                                                ResultCode.RESULT_FAIL, null);
                                    }

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onRestError(RestError error) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                                    Log.e("Order Post Failed","Post Order  failedddddddddddddddddddd");
                                    i = i + 1;
                                    callback.onRestPostDataCompleted(
                                            ResultCode.RESULT_FAIL, null);
                                }
                            });
        } else {
            callback.onRestPostDataCompleted(ResultCode.RESULT_FAIL, null);
        }

    }
```

And am pretty sure my url is correct.

Thanks:).

Comment: Try formatting your code using indentations to actually make the code readable. You're more likely to get help that way.

Comment: sorry am just edit my question .

Comment: This doesn't convey much, most of the logic is abstracted by method names. When is this called? If its on resume it might be due to app focus changing, etc.

Comment: Same problem here, my server shows multiple requests. And I am NOT calling this function twice.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your method is being called twice. Check where you are calling out the method - this might be occurred thanks to misunderstanding of Activity/Fragment lifecycle.

Put a print in the beginning of your invoke method and check, if it prints out twice.